# Custom query object with Simple-Fields custom date field

Tags: query, plugin-simple-fields

I'm currently using the [simple-fields plugin](http://simple-fields.com/) to add an event start date field that is a `date` type field to a custom post type called an 'event'. On my homepage I'm looking to display the three closest events to today's date that haven't passed today's date.

I currently have:

`$recent_events = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'phelps_event', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'order' => 'DESC'));`

but that just gives me the first 3 events in the order they were created. I'm not sure how I would filter by the date field I created with the simple-fields plugin.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Milo says, Simple Fields currently stores the dates in a much non preferred way.

I can think of two ways to solve this right now:

One: Fetch the posts "manually" using sql and use mysql function substr to re-make the dates to a valid format that you can sort on. A bit cumbersome, but would work.

The SQL query would look something like:

```
SELECT 
post_id,
DATE_FORMAT(concat(substr(_your_date_meta_key, 7, 4), "-",substr(_your_date_meta_key, 4,     2),"-",substr(_your_date_meta_key, 1, 2)), '%Y %b %D') as theDate
from wp_postmeta
where meta_key = "_your_date_meta_key"
order by theDate
```

And you would get the post ids in return, and then you can fetch just those ids using get_post() or similar.

Two: Fetch all posts using wp_query (as you already done) and then sort them in PHP using usort(). Depending on how many posts you have this could work pretty well.

(Three: Wait a couple of days and let me update Simple Fields with support for storing the dates as unixdates, since it makes so much more sense!)

Comment: I have time to wait and if not the usort idea seems solid! Pär, you've been so helpful with my questions the past few days. Thank you much!

Comment: Don't know if you saw this, but a version with a new kind of date picker has been released now: http://simple-fields.com/2012/date-and-time-picker-field-added-to-latest-version/

Comment: Yep already on it! I just had one last question regarding what I could use as the meta_value in a query to exclude items with a time before the present. I asked in more detail here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/sort-wp_query-by-date-and-time-field-but-only-include-results-that-havent-past?replies=1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you use the plugin's datepicker, it unfortunately enters the date in a format that makes it difficult to query by date. Dates should be in format `yyyy-mm-dd`, the plugin saves it backwards- `dd-mm-yyyy` which results in strange things like the 26th of September 1960 coming after the 25th of October 2012.

If it's possible to reverse the date format somehow (which is probably a question for the plugin's developer) you would simply need to get the meta key the date is saved under. In simple fields that's accomplished by clicking the `Show custom field keys` when editing a post, which will look something like:

```
Meta key: _simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_1_numInSet_0
```

For an alternative, I would recommend using something like [this meta box class](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) instead, which has a configurable date format.

That said, to query by a custom field date, you would do a [meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) on the key the date is saved under:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_key' => '_your_date_meta_key',
    'meta_value' => $today,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```